# Reverse a mult dimensional array - functional programming style

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array, collections, functional-programming

I was stumped coming up with a functional way to reverse a multi-dimmensional (even dimensions) array in Ruby.
input:  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
output: [[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]

This iterative solution works.

```
def reverse(arr)
  size = arr.length
  output = Array.new(size) { Array.new(size,0) }
  arr.reverse.each_with_index do |a, i|
    a.each_with_index do |a, j|
      output[j][i] = a
    end
  end
  output
end
```

Anyone have any insight into how to do using more of functional programming style and without referring to an explicit index?

Answer (score 6):

If `array` is your input, then it is as simple as

```
result = array.transpose.map(&:reverse)
```

if I understand your desired output correctly. ;)

To elaborate a bit: [`Array#transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) basically "mirrors" the 2D array along the main diagonal:

```
transposed = array.transpose  #=> [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

You seem to want that only with all the rows reversed, which is handled by the call to [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
result = transposed.map(&:reverse)  #=> [[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
```

The `map(&:reverse)` syntax is only shorthand for `map { |a| a.reverse }` and is enabled by [this](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) method.

#### Doing it by hand

After my initial answer it turned out in the comments that the OP is actually after a functional implementation of `transpose`. Here is what I came up with:

```
def transpose(a)
  (0...a[0].length).map { |i|
    (0...a.length).map { |j| a[j][i] }
  }
end
```

Although this does refer to explicit indices, it is a pure function composed of other pure functions, so it at least meets *my* definition of functional. ;)

Comment: Nice answer. It would be helpful to include a link to the [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) or give a quick demo of how it works.

Comment: That's the right output and certainly the good way for client code. Thinking about it, my real curiosity was to look for a functional way to code Array#transpose.

Comment: You are right @sagarpandya82, I elaborated a bit, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @radlab Added something for you, too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by taking a machete to it. More is not always better. Firstly, because the OP is new to SO, and therefore probably a Ruby newbie, I agree that some explanation would be helpful. However, you needn't explain what [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) does; just give the link (and the link for `map`) and show the result when `array` equals "input" in the OP's example. imo, better to write (indented, as code) `a = array.transpose #=> [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]` than to state the result. (cont.)...

Comment: ...That way you can then write `a.map(&:reverse)`, explaining that that gives the same result as `a.map { |b| b.reverse }`. You should also explain why yours is a "functional approach".  Everything from "Before looking up `transpose`," to the end is a bad example of the use of Ruby (more like C) and a distraction. Off with its head! Despite these criticisms, I upvoted.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the feedback. I rewrote the answer a bit more, but I don't agree with everything you said: First of the OP specifically asked for a possible implementation of `transpose`, so I'm leaving that in. Secondly I don't think that my `transpose` is all C-like. It does not concern itself with creating new arrays or appending elements to existing ones. It doesn't even explicitly assign any of the outputs elements. I think it is a good way to write `transpose` in Ruby if one were to do so, but I would love to see a more Ruby-ish version if you had something specific in mind.

Comment: I missed the request for an implementation of `transpose`. A Rubyish way would be `def transpose(arr); (arr.first).zip(*arr[1..-1]); end`. When I said your implementation was "C-like" I was referring to your use of array indices.

Comment: Okay, I see that this is more Rubyish in that it is very concise but for me the more important part of "Rubyish" is easlily readable/comprehensible. I had to think for a moment about why your solution works, whereas in the above version I see two indices which somehow get flipped in their usage, which is basically the essence of a transposition.

Comment: Julian, you've raised an important issue. My opinion is that it's always better to code in the most Rubyish manner. Yes, readers may have to exercise the little grey cells to understand what you've written, but they will learn something new about the power of the language, beyond the obtuse snippet. With practice, more and more of the Rubyish way will make its way into the subconscious, making it easier to understand and faster to read.

Comment: @JulianKniephof  Thanks, that's a nice simple functional programming example at the end.

Answer (score 4):

```
ar =  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

ar.reverse.transpose # => [[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

arr_rev = arr.reverse
  #=> [[7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]] 
arr_rev.first.zip *arr_rev[1..-1]
  #=> [[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
```

I believe this satisfies the requirements of [functional programming](https://www.sitepoint.com/functional-programming-techniques-with-ruby-part-i/).

The steps:

```
arr_rev = arr.reverse
   #=> [[7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]] 
arr_rev.first.zip(arr_rev[1..-1])
   #=> [7, 8, 9].zip(*[[4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]])
   #.    [7, 8, 9].zip([4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3])
   #.    [[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
```

See [Enumerable#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip).

Comment: Any chance you could explain how `zip(*arr_rev)` part works?

Comment: @sagarpandya82, please see my edit (which I should have provided without having been asked).

Comment: Yes I really needed the steps here thank you. I've never seen `*` used like this, it seems to work like an anti-splat if I'm correct?

Comment: No, that's the normal use of splat: it replaces an array with a list of its elements.

Comment: Ah this is what meant by anti-splat. Anyhow has cleared things up for me, thanks.

Comment: I don't think that `shift` can be considered functional.

Comment: Another curious way of doing it that I just got from another question and that might be even more Ruby-ish is `arr_rev.inject(&:zip).map(&:flatten)`. ;)

Comment: @Julian, I like it!